# angularjs controller with video

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a snippet of code below, and what it does is when the image is clicked, it displays the video underneath. I am simply trying to align the video to be the same size as the image and fit snug underneathe it but make the image disappear as well. That way once the image is clicked, the video will displays seamlessly. Any help would be great!

```js
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-media.js"></script>



<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['media']);

myApp.controller('MoocCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


 
   $scope.videoSources = [];
    
    $scope.loadVideos = function() {
            $scope.videoSources.push('https://example.com/images/Intro.mp4');
      
        };




});
  
    
    
  

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-App="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="MoocCtrl">
   
  
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 vidPlayer">
<a href="#" class="ImgButton" ng-click="loadVideos()"><img src="images/introImage.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
   
 
</div>
      <video html5-video='{{ videoSources }}'autoplay='true' controls='true'></video>
    </div>



</body>
```

Comment: Why can't you add a thumbnail to the video? Html5 video tag have an option to add thumbnail image

Comment: i think a thumbnail would be too small. I have an image that takes on the size of the div. I would like the video to take on the size as well

Comment: You can specify width and height of the video. I think the image also will automatically change